# Marshall java class to the following xml scheme

Tags: jaxb

I've arranged with my frontend developers that the XML data returned by a webservice has to be in the following format:

```
<week_program state="on" > 
 <day name="Monday">
  <switch type= "day" state= "on">12:00</switch>
  <switch type= "night" state= "on">13:00</switch>
  ...
  <switch type= "day" state= "off">17:00</switch>
  <switch type= "night" state= "on">22:00</switch>
 </day>
 <day name="Tuesday">...</day>
 <day name="Wednesday">...</day>
 <day name="Thursday">...</day>
 <day name="Friday">...</day>
 <day name="Saturday">...</day>
 <day name="Sunday">...</day>
</week_program>
```

How can I create my class so that when I marshall the class with JAXB, I'll automatically get this scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You will have classes like `WeekProgram`, `Day`, and `Switch` with relationships between them.  `WeekProgram` will have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

`Switch` will make use of `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlValue`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Note that by default JAXB will expect the annotations to be on the get (or set) methods.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.htm